# how to wrap text inside a specific width and height using javascript with scroll up and scroll down

Tags: javascript, scrollbar, word-wrap

Im very new in javascript and i'm using it to create an interactive website but there is a problem. Since i just started all i know is how to warpText my content and i don't know how can i make a code in javascript that has the function that if the wrapText overflow in the given width and height. a scroll up and down will appear and help navigate the ones that are not sceen.

this is what i use:

```
function wrapText(text, x, y, maxWidth, lineHeight)
{
  var words = text.split('');
  var line = '';
  for(var n = 0; n < words.length; n++)
  {
    var testLine = line + words[n] + '';
    var metrics = content.measureText(testLine);
    var testWidth = metrics.width;
    if(testWidth > maxWidth)
    {
      context.fillText(line, x, y);
      line = words[n] + '';y += lineHeight;
    }
    else {
           line = textLine;
         }
   }
context.fillText(line, x, y);
}
```

in function draw:

```
wrapText(currentText, 45, 460, 800, 20);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's [my jsFiddle solution](http://jsfiddle.net/jedhunsaker/r34rn/). I think your solution requires just plain HTML/CSS:

HTML:

```
<div id="foo" class="wrap">...</div>
```

And your CSS:

```
#foo {
    width: 400px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: yellowgreen;
}

.wrap {
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```